# Adding another string with Input, by clicking button

Tags: jquery, input

How do I do, that when user click button, appeared another string with `<Input>`?

And ID of Input will be grow.

I want something like this:

```
<button id="add">add</button>
<input id="e-1" type="text">
<input id="e-2" type="text">
....
```

No php please.. I'd prefer JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaf3V/)

This'll do it

#### HTML

```
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="inputs"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
var i = 0;
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#inputs").append('<input id="e-'+(++i)+'" type="text"><br>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <button class="container-add-input"></button>
    <input type='text' />
    <input type='text' />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".container-add-input").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().append("<input type='text' />");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I like the parent append idea, but you forgot the incremental id's